# Dynamic control inside a layout in android

Tags: android, layout

[image]I have an activity Which has Text to show then Some content under that then a list view.

While some content could be a picture, relative layout, Video control, or a linear layout. Depending upon the data it got from previous activity.

Is that possible to do that or I have to make separate layouts for all items?

Comment: Yes this is possible. Look for "multiple item layouts for listview"

Comment: for list view ? It is not listview, It is between list view and textview. And it will be only just on item amoung them [picture, relative layout, Video control, or a linear layout]

Comment: I have added image in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flSpecialContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can add any View you want in code to the FrameLayout (flSpecialContainer) based on what you need.

Comment: This seems my answer, but can you please tell me how add views in a framelayout programmatic.

Comment: Done that :) throught inflater then add view in frame layout. Thanks :)

Comment: Oké, nice. If you need more help, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

you can create all possible items in one layout and set visible and gone them depend on data you receive 
in this case you don't need create them in code , and can preview activity layout in design mode.